# CSS - How to make a container fit all availble height of a grandparent?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm working on a web application and have the issue with layout.

Here is the expected design, which consists of 3 major parts:

- Article Header
- Article Content
- Article Footer

[image: the expected design]

It is pretty easy to implement this design using CSS Flexbox.

```css
html, body, article {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}

.article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

  .article-header {
    background-color: orange;
  }
  
  .article-footer {
    background-color: green;
  }
  
  .article-content {
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: CornflowerBlue;  
  }
```

```html
<article class="article">
  <header class="article-header">Header</header>
  <div class="article-content">Article Content</div>
  <footer class="article-footer">Footer</footer>
</article>
```

However, in the real application HTML elements nesting is much deeper and sometimes not under control (given using 3rd party components or transclusion within Angular/React)

Therefore, HTML usually looks like this:

```css
html, body, article {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

  .article-header {
    background-color: orange;
  }
  
  .article-footer {
    background-color: green;
  }

  .article-wrapper {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
 
  .article-content {
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: CornflowerBlue;  
  }
```

```html
<article class="article">
  <header class="article-header">Header</header>
  <div class="article-wrapper">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="article-content">
           Article Content.
           Can I fit all available height?
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <footer class="article-footer">Footer</footer>
</article>
```

It seems that in this case only one way to make *.article-content* fit all available height is to add these styles to each container down the way from *.article-wrapper* to *article-content*:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-grow: 1;
```

But, as I mentioned, it is quite problematic since sometimes nesting is rather deep or container elements are generated by 3rd party components.

Please, let me know if there are better ways to achieve the required design.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If the content is long enough, it will fill the available height. Are you needing to set a background color or something? If so, you can set it on `<body>` maybe so that it shows through.

Comment: This is a good point! Unfortunately, the long content pushes the footer out of the screen whereas it should always stay at the page bottom.

Comment: @sorayadragon, I've got your point now! This is really helpful and can solve the problem in a pretty elegant way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only the direct children of a flex container that becomes flex item, and as such can apply the property `flex-grow: 1`.

So for this to work you need to give the `article-wrapper` and its `div` descendants down to `article-content` flex properties too, where all 3 need to be both a flex container and a flex item.

```
.article-wrapper,
.article-wrapper > div,
.article-wrapper > div > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Simply put, `.article-wrapper` is flex container to the first `div`, the first `div` will be flex item to `.article-wrapper` but also flex container to the second `div`, and so on.

*Updated*

*Also, according the image you posted, the `article-content` should scroll when content exceed it height, and for that to work I added `overflow: auto` to the `wrapper-content` rule*

Sample snippet

```css
html, body, article {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

  .article-header {
    background-color: orange;
  }
  
  .article-footer {
    background-color: green;
  }

  .article-wrapper {
     overflow: auto;
  }

  .article-wrapper,
  .article-wrapper > div,
  .article-wrapper > div > div {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .article-content {
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: CornflowerBlue;  
  }
```

```html
<article class="article">
  <header class="article-header">Header</header>
  <div class="article-wrapper">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="article-content">
           Article Content.
           Can I fit all available height?
           <br><br>
           Scroll overflowed content<br><br>
           Scroll overflowed content<br><br>
           Scroll overflowed content<br><br>
           Scroll overflowed content<br><br>
           Scroll overflowed content<br><br>
           Scroll overflowed content<br><br>
           Scroll overflowed content<br><br>
           Scroll overflowed content<br><br>
           Scroll overflowed content<br><br>
           Scroll overflowed content<br><br>
           Scroll overflowed content<br><br>
           Scroll overflowed content<br><br>
           Scroll overflowed content<br><br>
           Scroll overflowed content<br><br>
           Scroll overflowed content<br><br>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <footer class="article-footer">Footer</footer>
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer! This is really sad that with Flexbox and Grid specs the solution is still very tricky.